# How to know that the slope of the tangent line and gradient are orthogonal?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a surface $f(x, y) = z$, a level set for the surface, and a point on that set, how to know that the slope of the tangent line to the level curve and the gradient vector are orthogonal?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please 
improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes 
your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This 
information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them 
write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any $C^1$ path $c$, defined on an non-empty interval $J$ such that $c(J)$ is a subset of the domain of the $C^1$-map $f\colon\boldsymbol R^n\to\boldsymbol R$.  Then $f\mathop{\circ}c$  is a real-valued $C^1$-map defined on $J$.  Its derivative is according to the chain rule 
$$(f\mathop{\circ}c)'=\langle\nabla (f\mathop{\circ}c),c'\rangle.$$
Now if $c$ is a level curve, $f\mathop{\circ}c$ is constant, hence $(f\mathop{\circ}c)'=0$.